# Mounting local directory into Docker container path that is not exposed as a VOLUME

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there any difference between:

1. Mounting a host directory into a container path (the path is not exposed as a volume), e.g.:

`docker run -v /host/directory:/container/directory my_image command_to_run`

`Dockerfile` of `my_image` **does not** include `VOLUME ["/container/directory"]`

2. Mounting a host directory into a a container path exposed as a volume:

`docker run -v /host/directory:/container/directory my_image command_to_run`

`Dockerfile` of `my_image` **includes** `VOLUME ["/container/directory"]`

I know that volume data persists independent of the container life-cycle. However, since I want to work on my local data from within a container, does that make any difference if the mount-point inside the container is a volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference if you mount the path from the host into the container. The filesystem from the host will be mounted over top of that directory inside the container.

The difference between listing the volume and not listing it inside the image is the behavior of docker when you create an image without specifying a volume. When the volume is defined on the image, docker will create an "anonymous" volume you can see with `docker volume ls` as a long uuid string. These volumes are rarely useful, so I recommend against defining a volume in the image and instead only defining them on your `docker run` command or `docker-compose.yml` definition.

Downsides of defining a volume in the image include:

1. Later lines in the Dockerfile or in descendant Dockerfile's may not be able to change the contents at this location. Docker's behavior with this varies by scenario and version, so for predictability, once a volume is defined in an image, I consider that directory off limits.
2. Creation of anonymous volumes are difficult to use and are likely to clutter up the filesystem.

I posted a [blog](https://boxboat.com/2017/01/23/volumes-and-dockerfiles-dont-mix/) on this topic a while back if you're interested in more details.

Comment: Hi, this is a great answer, thanks. There is one point I'd like to address. Afaik, defining a volume at the image level is essential for data persistence produced by that image. E.g. the official MySQL image would specify `VOLUME /var/lib/mysql` in order to persist the data. In cases like this one, defining a volume at `docker run` or with `compose` would not be feasible.

Comment: The `VOLUME` syntax for the docker images was used when data containers were common. It was a shorthand to avoid defining volumes in your `run` or `compose` and data containers were referenced by the container name vs the volume name. That's been replaced with named volumes which you have to create a runtime. There's no requirement to define these at build time, any directory can be made a volume at run time.